# Word for something that threatens its own existence

Tags: single-word-requests

As in the title: What's a word for something that threatens its own existence?

I know "self-destructive" is an option, but it doesn't actually destroy itself, just inevitably poses an existential threat to itself. I was thinking "ouroboric," like something that consumes itself. Maybe "apoptotic" ("apoptosis" being programmed cell death) would make sense, not sure what you guys think about that one.

Context: I'm talking about a novel that portrays writing (and literature) as fundamentally meaningless. Further analysis of this novel shows that this isn't actually a problem, so the novel's representation of literature isn't inherently self-destructive. But it poses a threat to itself—it undermines its own relevance and meaningfulness (since it is itself a piece of literature). So I'm trying to describe this particular characteristic of the novel.

Comment: The problem seems to be existential - "Could such a thing exist?" Something that threatens its own existence, but never actually does the action that would destroy it? Such a thing would not even qualify as "potentially self-destructive", as one of those things would never have actually done it.  == Some further clarification is required, e.g. context and a sample sentence.

Comment: Suicidal? More context would be better here.

Comment: If you seek an invented word, we have a [conlang.se] site on the network. Just make sure to take their tour and read-up their help centre. FWIW "asymptotropic". Have fun.

Comment: Thanks everyone! I've added some context to help :) Also @Greybeard, I think this is an inherently paradoxical or self-defeating relationship, so in many ways, you're right on the nose there

Comment: I would pick "human".

Comment: @ Bitter dreggs Excellent. A site that will handle the off-topic 'Can I make up a word meaning ...?' questions. Thank you for the update.

Comment: Perhaps "self-defeating" after reading your third paragraph.

Comment: You're not perhaps thinking ["postmodernist"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postmodernism#Overview) are you - "denies the existence of a universal, stable reality... denying or challenging the validity of scientific inquiry, or declaiming the arbitrariness of the aesthetics of artistic works or other artefacts of cultural production" - therefore possibly denying the value of it's own reasoning and merit?

Comment: Autophagous maybe?

Comment: If you don't mind a phrase, *a novel that digs its own grave*?